# how refresh login page after form valid fail without the confirm box in django?

Tags: python, django, http, django-forms, post-redirect-get

this is my login func in view.py

```
def login_user(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None )
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    # Redirect to a success page.
                    userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(user = user)
                    request.session['userprofile'] = userprofile
                    request.session['familymembers'] = UserProfile.objects.filter(family = userprofile.family)

                    return redirect('/profile')
                else:
                # Return a 'disabled account' error message
                    messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, '.')
                    return redirect('/profile')

            else:
                messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, '.')
                return render_to_response('registration/login.html',{'form':form},RequestContext(request))

        return render_to_response('registration/login.html', {'form': form},RequestContext(request))
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_to_response('registration/login.html',{'form':form},context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

when the form `is_valid()` failed , same login page showed with error messages, 
now when i refresh the page, an confirm box pop up says resubmit the form confirm,

my question is: is possible to avoid this confirm box， i tried

```
        return redirect('/', {'form': form},RequestContext(request))
```

this will avoid confirm box, but the valid error message is gone.

Comment: Please look at the example in the [django site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view), and tell if it helps or not.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect response itself does not contain extra info, you could store the form into `session` by serializing `form.data` and retrieve it later in the view.
Or use Ajax to submit which does not make whole page refreshing.

Comment: sorry for the delay, so you mean this is mean to be that way? in order to use form is_valid() i can not refresh the form page?

Comment: @chenliang I'm a bit confused now. The redirection would dismiss the re-submit dialog, but it does not carry extra info such as `form` or even `form.errors`. Thus if you want to use `form.error` after redirection, you need to store it somewhere such as in session, cookie or the querystring of the redirection target. On the other hand, yes you cannot redirect the page in order to use `form` variable inside template.

Answer (score 0):

> I got this same problem, I solve that with this tiny logic

```
login(request, user)
reverse_lazy('index') # here the tiny logic works 
return redirect('index')
```

**Explaination**

When ever login happens in the same page if we press refresh first time it return that form confirmation box, But in second reload it will not showing

The logic is using reverse_lazy I refresh first time already and second that page return again so we already crossed the problem

***My question***

But I don't know why confirmation box is showing after the form is submitted I need that answer friends I am waiting for that